# What is the meaning of Kalki purana 4.15

Tags: kalki, kalki-purana

In the Kalki purana chapter 4 verse 15 it stated that:

> Being pleased by their devotional service, I incarnate, along with Goddess Lakshmi, in every millennium."

What is meant by this verse? A millenium is 1000 years. There are 10 avatars of Vishnu per kalpa. Is it a mistake? Do they mean a kalpa or mahayuga?

Comment: Give the sanskrit verses. Sometimes translators translate "Yuga" as a millennium so it is confusing. Give the exact T sanskrit verse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a translation issue, here is the Sanskrit shloka and Hindi translation of **Kalki Purana 4.15**:

[image: sambhavami yuge yuge संभवामि युगे युगे in Sanskrit shloka]

> The religion of the Brahmanas is to render pure devotional service
> unto Me. Being pleased by their devotional service, I incarnate, along
> with Goddess Laksmi (Shri), from age to age.

---

### Are there 10 avatars of Vishnu per kalpa?

There are infinite avatars of Vishnu, few of them are given in this post:

[Mahavishnu's Avataaras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23092/12304)

10 or 24 are most famous among all avatars but they are not the only avatars.

---

The phrase संभवामि युगे युगे (sambhavami yuge yuge) is there in **Shrimad Bhagavad Gita 4.8** too:

> परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम्।
>
> धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय **संभवामि युगे युगे**।।4.8।।

And [here](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=8&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1) is how different scholars translated it:

> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: Paritranaya, for the protection; sadhunam, of the pious, the followers of the virtuous path; vinasaya, for the destruction; duskrtam, of the evil-doers, of the sinful ones; and also dharmasamsthapanarthaya, for establishing virtue fully;-for that purpose, sambhavami, I manifest Myself; yuge yuge, in every age. -*English Translation Of Sri Shankaracharya's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Gambirananda*
>
> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: For the protection of the good and also for the destruction of the wicked, for the establishment of Dharma, am **I born from age to age**. -*English Translation By Swami Adidevananda*
>
> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: For the protection of the pious, the destruction of the evil-doers, and establishing virtue, I manifest Myself in every age. -*English Translation By Swami Gambirananda*
>
> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: For the protection of the good, for the destruction of the wicked and for the establishment of righteousness, I am born in every age. -*English Translation By Swami Sivananda*
>
> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: For the protection of the good people, and for the destruction of evil-doers, and for the purpose of firmly establishing righteousness, I take birth in every age. -*English Translation By By Dr. S. Sankaranarayan*
>
> [Lord Shri Krishna to Arjuna]: To protect the righteous, to destroy the wicked and to establish the kingdom of God, **I am reborn from age to age**. -*English Translation by Shri Purohit Swami*

Answer (score 5):

[Sanskrit](https://archive.org/stream/KalkiPuranaSanskrit1890/Kalki%20Purana%20Sanskrit%201890#page/n19/mode/2up) word used is "Yuga" and [translation](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByTCDrDij9HBWVA4VHYzY2g4elU/edit) you quoted is given by  by Bhumipatidas. Gaudiya Sampradaya (ISKCON) Swamis and Acharyas translate "Yuga" as millenium.

> यो धर्मो ब्राह्मणाना हि सा भक्तिर्मम पुप्फला । 
>  तयाहं तोषितः
>   श्रीशः सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥ १५
>
> The dharma of the brahmanas is to render pure devotional service unto
>   Me .Being pleased by their devotional service, I incarnate, along with
>   Goddess Laksmi, in every millennium.

This quote is similar to [Bhagavadgita Gita 4.8](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-4-8/)

> परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् । 
>  धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय
>   सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥८॥
>
> paritrāṇāya sādhūnāḿ vināśāya ca duṣkṛtām 
>   dharma-saḿsthāpanārthāya sambhavāmi yuge yuge
>
> To deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to
>   reestablish the principles of religion, I Myself appear, millennium
>   after millennium.

Yuga is  translated as "Age" or "Millenium" or to convey a time that occurs at required intervals. Here is how A Mahadeva Sastri [translates it](https://archive.org/stream/bhagavadgitawith00maharich#page/106/mode/2up) in his translation of commentary of Bhagavadgita.

> 8. For the protection of the good, for the  destruction of evil-doers, for the firm establishment  of religion, I am born in every age.

**There are 10 avatars of Vishnu per kalpa. Is it a mistake?**

Lord Vishnu avatars are infinite if we consider cyclic nature of time. However, Puranas mention [some avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19956/3500)  of Lord Vishnu. There's no rule that Lord Vishnu has to take only 10 Avatars in a Kalpa.  Also, [refer this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21996/3500)  for chronological order of Vishnu's avatars.

Comment: Ohh.. I was writing answer..and didn't see ur answer..

Comment: @YDS We can have two answers and Your answer is good and explains word Yuga as age. I will also add it answer to make it more clear.